# NamedQueries in JPA

Tags: java, sql, jpa, named-query

From what I know, UPDATE and DELETE can be done by *NamedQueries*.

However,

```
void updateName (int ID, String name) {        

   EntityManager entityManager = 
      Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("uPU").createEntityManager();
   Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Users.updateName");
   query.setParameter("name", name);
   query.setParameter("id", ID);
}
```

isn't doing the update.

The named query is as follows:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Users.updateName", query = "UPDATE Users u SET u.name = :name "
        + "WHERE u.id = :id "),
```

A similar thing going on with DELETE.

Nothing wrong with SELECT on *Namedqueries*.

Is there something more to altering the contents of an SQL table with *NamedQueries*?

//================================

**ADD:**

i'm using a **namedquery**.

From what I know, opening the transaction and commiting it is not necessary on namedQueries.

```
query.executeUpdate();
```

gives a runtime error.

//================================

**ADD2:**

The code is giving no compile or runtime errors except to that addition suggested by DataNucleus below. see my previous edition above regarding that suggestion.

Comment: That addition that was "suggested" is essential. And what is the exception/error when you add that?

Answer (score 1):

Thought about actually executing the query? All you've done there is create it.

```
query.executeUpdate()
```

http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jpa/jpql.html#JPQL_UPDATE_Queries

Comment: see my edit after the line comment. special emphasis on named query.

Comment: If you have an exception don't you think people would like to see it (and its stacktrace)? If the exception is a TransactionRequiredException, then that is what the JPA spec says will be thrown if no tx is present ("named" or otherwise) - look at the spec. Obviously that depends on your JPA implementation too, since some (e.g DataNucleus JPA) allow nontransactional operations.